# shell read and pass mulptiple variables in for or while loop

Tags: bash, shell, ssh, hive, sh

Below is my input file and the code I am using
FILE :

```
cat $TESTFILE
2020-01-13,COST_CH_RPT
2018-04-19,LOSS_CH_RPT
```

CODE :

```
for i in `cat $TESTFILE`
do
   export date=`cat $TESTFILE|cut -d',' -f1`
      echo date=$date
   export Name=`cat $TESTFILE|cut -d',' -f2`
      echo Name=$Name
beeline --outputformat=csv2 --hivevar Name=$Name --hivevar date=$date  -u ${beeURL} -f TEST.hql
done
```

The objective is to run the hql file for every line in the file , the above code is running twice for the two lines available , but the variables that are being passed for both the runs is the same , which is the first line in the file .
How can i differentiate the input variables for each run.

Comment: I'm sure someone will dig up a duplicate question soon, but in the meantime: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Especially the ["Field splitting, ..." section of BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001#Field_splitting.2C_whitespace_trimming.2C_and_other_input_processing). You can have `read` do the field splitting and avoid the `cut` stuff.

Comment: BTW, the immediate problem with what you're doing now is that every time you use `cat $TESTFILE`, it reads the *entire file*, not just the current line. `echo "$i" | cut ...` would be the direct fix, but really using a `read` loop simplifies everything.

Comment: Don't use `export` when a simple assignment will do.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by comment, the current solution re-process the TESTFILE multiple times, incorrectly. Simpler alternative is to use the 'read' to loop thru the lines:

```
while IFS=, read date Name ; do
    echo beeline --outputformat=csv2 --hivevar Name="$Name" --hivevar date="$date"  -u "${beeURL}" -f TEST.hql
done < $TESTFILE
```

It simply iterate over the line in the TESTFILE, and execute the beeline command. Suggesting using quotes to protect against error in the input file - in particular, spaces, which will 'break' the command line.